# Bad performance in Java exercise

Tags: java, performance

I'm doing some tests in Java to warm up, and I just made this one:

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.
>   The consecutive elements of array A represent consecutive cars on a
>   road.
>
> Array A contains only 0s and/or 1s:
>
> 0 represents a car traveling east, 1 represents a car traveling west.
>   The goal is to count passing cars. We say that a pair of cars (P, Q),
>   where 0 ≤ P < Q < N, is passing when P is traveling to the east and Q
>   is traveling to the west.
>
> For example, consider array A such that:
>
> A[0] = 0   A[1] = 1   A[2] = 0   A[3] = 1   A[4] = 1 We have five
>   pairs of passing cars: (0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4).
>
> Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
>
> that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N integers, returns
>   the number of pairs of passing cars.
>
> The function should return −1 if the number of pairs of passing cars
>   exceeds 1,000,000,000.
>
> For example, given:
>
> A[0] = 0   A[1] = 1   A[2] = 0   A[3] = 1   A[4] = 1 the function
>   should return 5, as explained above.
>
> Assume that:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A
>   is an integer that can have one of the following values: 0, 1.
>   Complexity:
>
> expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected worst-case space
>   complexity is O(1), beyond input storage (not counting the storage
>   required for input arguments). Elements of input arrays can be
>   modified.

My code is as follows:

```
public int solution(int[] A) {
        // write your code in Java SE 8
        int result = 0;
        long mult = 0;

        for(int value : A){

            if(value == 0){
                mult ++;        
            }
            else {
                result += mult;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

The link with the result is this one:
https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingFFF4BS-AZ3/

If the link die, the result said:

> Performance tests
>
> ▶ medium_random  random, length = ~10,000 ✔OK ▶ large_random  random,
>   length = ~100,000 ✘WRONG ANSWER  got 1248768710 expected -1 ▶
>   large_big_answer 
>   0..01..1, length = ~100,000 ✘WRONG ANSWER  got -1794967296 expected -1 ▶ large_alternate 
>   0101..01, length = ~100,000 ✘WRONG ANSWER  got 1250025000 expected -1 ▶ large_extreme  large test with all 1s/0s, length = ~100,000 ✔OK

Any ideas what is wrong in my code?.

Comment: You don't stop after exceeding 1,000,000,000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your rules say,

> The function should return −1 if the number of pairs of passing cars exceeds 1,000,000,000.

And you don't test that condition. You could with a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) and something like

```
return result > 1000000000 ? -1 : result;
```

or (debateably) more readable

```
if (result > 1000000000) {
    return -1;
}
return result;
```

and for improved performance you might add that test like

```
for (int value : A) {
    if (value == 0) {
        mult++;
    } else {
        result += mult;
        if (result > 1000000000) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
return result;
```